# caching static pages served from database

Tags: laravel, caching

I just moved to Laravel a few days ago, so I am still new in this framework... I have static html pages stored in the database (a big number of pages), and visitors can request those pages by typing the related URL. I would like to improve performance by caching them, What is the best way to do that in Laravel ? and how to remove the cached page if it's removed from the database ?

Answer (score 1):

> Laravel provides a unified API for various caching systems.

I **highly recommend** to have a look at the documentation.

[Laravel Cache Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/cache)

You could cache the pages forever, and once you delete them you call `forget()` method in Cache

**Retrieve Or Update**

```
$value = Cache::rememberForever('users', function() {
    return DB::table('users')->get();
});

$value = Cache::remember('users', $minutes, function() {
    return DB::table('users')->get();
});
```

**Store**

```
Cache::put('key', 'value', $minutes);
```

**Deleting from cache**

```
Cache::forget('key');
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer, when I edit the page in database can I update the cache as well ? also I see a lot of method for caching (redis, memcache etc ...) which one is good in my situation ?

Comment: They are ```drivers```. You could cache locally, or in-memory key/value store (memcached). That depend on you. Read about them see what is the best for you.

Comment: thanks! how to update the cache when the page is edited ?

Comment: ```For larger applications, it is recommended that you use an in-memory cache such as Memcached or APC``` from documentation.

Comment: For that you may use ```flush()``` it is explained also in the documentation as well.

Comment: Also see **Retrieve Or Update** example.

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cache;
use Carbon\Carbon;


class Page extends Model
{
    public function getPage($url)
    {
        if (Cache::has($url))
        {
            $page = Cache::get($url);
        }
        else {
            $page = self::where(['confirm'=> 1, 'url'=> $url])->first();
            $expiresAt = Carbon::now()->addHours(12);
            Cache::put($url, $page, $expiresAt);
        }

        return $page;

    }
}
```

Очиска кеша:

```
Cache::flush();
```

Comment: @IIyaYaremchuk how I can update a specific cache if a page is edited in the database ?

Comment: @medBo Cache::put($url, $page, $expiresAt);

Comment: @IIyaYaremchuk will this update the cache if it already exist ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the Cache documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/cache

This post could be interesting https://scotch.io/tutorials/caching-in-laravel-with-speed-comparisons